# How to plot multiple lines in a single graph using HighChart with JSON

Tags: json, highcharts, linegraph

Here is my code for plotting multiple line in a single grpah but it doesn,t working

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
//var line2 = $.parseJSON(document.getElementById("test").value);
var line2 = $.parseJSON(document.getElementById("test").value);
alert(line2);
var mydata = [
];
var mydata1 = [
];
var mydata2 = [
];
for (var i = 0; i < line2.length; i++) {
    //mydata[0].push([line2[i].time,line2[i].valueint]);
    mydata.push(line2[i].time);
    mydata1.push(line2[i].valueint);
    mydata2.push(line2[i].valueint1);
}
console.log(mydata,mydata1); 

$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Vitals Chart',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date & Time'
        },
        categories: mydata
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },      
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temp',
        data: mydata1
        },
        {
        name: 'Temp',
        data: mydata2                   

    }]
});
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>


    <input type="hidden" id="test" value='[{"time":"2013-06-27 20:28:04","valueint":40","valueint1":64},{"time":"2013-07-0110:41:29","valueint":11","valueint1":11},{"time":"2013-07-17 18:55:02","valueint":40","valueint1":43}]
    '>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 450px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If any one got this idea please update this code as JSFidle.Actuallu im doing this in JSP Web Application In this code in single line graph its works perfect but in mulple line thier is an erro

Comment: How to plot multiple lines in a single graph

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because Highcharts uses timestamps (time in milliseconds), so dates like "2013-06-27 20:28:04" are incorrect. `"valueint":40"` have extra quate. In case when you have a push object, you need to have y parameter with value, instead of custom name.

Comment: Sir,without valueint1 it works well See this link Live jsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/4MQp5/2   but using valueint1 it doesnt work .please update this code

Comment: Live fiddle: [link](jsfiddle.net/4MQp5/2)

Comment: Link is fine, but all works fine, as I'm seeing, so could you attach also link to wrong chart ?

Comment: Last day your colleque Pawel Fus help me about that..But i need multiple lines in single chart..

Comment: [{"time":"2013-06-27 20:28:04","valueint":40","valueint1":64},{"time":"2013-07-0110:41:29","valueint":11","valueint1":11},{"time":"2013-07-17 18:55:02","valueint":40","valueint1":43}]  this my json script

Comment: I found the JSON in your first post, anyway I sent you the link.

Comment: Yea Sebastian Really Working